# How to read 8 bit ascii from terminal in linux

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ascii

I'm running ubuntu 16, and am using a bash script in the terminal that reads the stdout of a program. The c++ program uses putchar to output 8 bit characters to the terminal through stdout. I try to capture that output in the bash script and print the ascii decimal representation.

For example, if the program outputs 'A', the bash script would convert and print 65 as the corresponding ascii. However, when the program outputs a weird character outside the 0-127 range, all I get is 32767 instead of the correct decimal. It seems that bash on ubuntu is not capable of non standard 8 bit ascii.

I currently use something like this to convert to decimal:

```
decimal=$(printf '%d' "'$char")
```

Is there any way I can convert the character from stdout to a decimal value on the linux command line?

Comment: There's no such thing as "8 bit ASCII" -- ASCII is a 7-bit code.  There are various 8-bit character encodings that include ASCII as codes 0-127 (such as iso8859 and UTF-8) -- maybe you mean one of them?

Answer (score 1):

Try `xxd -p` instead.
For instance,

```
char=$'\xff'
decimal=$(( 16#$(printf "%c" "$char" | xxd -p) ))
echo "$decimal"
```

yields:

```
255
```

Here's the test script for the characters between 0 and 255:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((i=0; i<256; i++)); do
    hex=$(printf "%x" $i)
    char=$(printf "\x${hex}")
    if [[ "$i" -eq 10 ]]; then
        char=$'\n'
    fi
    # The if statement above is a workaround to generate the test sequence
    # properly because $( ... ) chops of the trailing newline
    # and is not essential for the conversion code below

    decimal=$(( 16#$(printf "%c" "$char" | xxd -p) ))
    echo "$i => $decimal"
done
```

**Explanation:**

- `printf "%c" "$char" | xxd -p` returns hex string, `ff` in this case.
- `$(( 16#hexval ))` converts the hexadecimal value to decimal.

although I'd recommend to use other language like `python` or `perl` for flexibility and efficiency. Here's the perl version:

```
decimal=$(printf "%c" "$char" | perl -ne 'print unpack("%C", $_)' )
```

Comment: this is better, but still some numbers are getting messed up. 205 gets changed to 52583 but 243 and 255 work fine for example...

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I should have examined my code with whole characters from 0 to 255. I found some mistranslations with tab, newline, whitespace etc., although I could not reproduce the output 52583 for input 205.
I've corrected my answer and added a perl solution just in case.
BR.